Conservation of energy during electromagnet repulsion
Scenario
Consider a coil with some internal resistance connected to battery.
To give some example values, let's say the battery has capacity 4 Ah and voltage 1.5 V. So the total energy of the battery is 4 * 1.5 = 6 Wh. The coil's resistance is 100 Ohms.
As I understand it, if I let the battery run out, then the coil will have dissipated the battery's energy as heat. Thus 6 Wh will have been dissipated in the coil.
Now we put a permanent magnet inside the coil. We orient the magnet so that it will be repelled by the coil and we rerun the experiment with a fresh 6 Wh battery.
Question
Since the magnet is repelled by the coil it will attain some kinetic energy that will eventually turn to heat (due to friction). Thus there is a non-zero amount of energy ending up in the magnet (in the form of either kinetic energy or heat). But at the same time, the coil will eventually have dissipated all of the battery's energy as heat. We have:
Input energy = Battery Energy = 6 Wh
Output energy = Heat dissipated from coil + heat/kinetic energy of magnet.
Since input energy must equal output energy as per the law of conservation of energy, it must follow that some of the energy from the battery somehow does not run through the coil as current and instead ends up in the magnet. How can this be?

If the magnet is permitted to accelerate, then it will have received kinetic energy from the battery, but if it's held immobile (with respect to the coil), then it won't. Remember that work done is the product of force and distance, and if the distance moved is zero, then work done must be zero. I'll be assuming from here on that the magnet physically accelerated.
Due to Lenz's law, the moving magnet induces a current in the coil which opposes current that produced the magnetic field in the first place, the field that moved it. In other words, current through the coil falls when the magnet is moving.
This behaviour can be described in electrical terms, by modelling the coil as an ideal zero-resistance coil with inductance \$L\$ in series with a "parasitic" resistance \$R\$ (in your case 100Ω):

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
According to Kirchhoff's Voltage law (KVL), the total EMF of cell V1 is shared between the coil's inductive part, and its resistive part:
$$ V_R + V_L = V_1 $$
After the magnetic field has built up and settled, inductor voltage \$V_L\$ falls to zero, and the entire cell EMF exists across \$R\$. This condition is shown on the voltmeters. In this steady state, current \$I\$ has reached a maximum, shown on ammeter AM1, and has settled at:
$$ I = \frac{V_1}{R} = 15mA $$
While current \$I\$ remains constant, then power delivered to the coil and lost as heat would be:
$$ P_R = I \times V_R = 22.5mW $$
In this steady state, the voltage across \$L\$ is zero, and the power being delivered to the inductance to build the magnetic field has also dropped to zero:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_L &= V_1 - V_R \\ \\
&= 1.5V - 1.5V \\ \\
&= 0V \\ \\
P_L &= I \times V_L \\ \\
&= 15mA \times 0V \\ \\
&= 0W
\end{aligned}
$$
If the magnet is released and permitted to accelerate, its motion would induce a current in the opposite direction to \$I\$, causing total current to fall. This behaviour is usually described as an induced EMF \$V_L\$ (an increase of \$V_L\$) coupled with a corresponding decrease of \$V_R\$, to maintain their sum equal to source \$V_1\$.
Let's pretend that current has fallen to 10mA, and see how this affects things. If current falls, then so does voltage \$V_R\$, according to Ohm's law:
$$ V_R = 10mA \times 100\Omega = 1V $$
\$V_1\$ didn't change though, and so inductor voltage \$V_L\$ must rise, to conform with KVL:
$$ V_L = V_1 - V_R = 0.5V $$
Heating power \$P_R\$ has reduced:
$$ P_R = I \times V_R = 10mA \times 1V = 10mW $$
Crucially, though, some power is now also being delivered to \$L\$ to maintain the magnetic field, which is losing energy by accelerating the magnet, energy which ultimately becomes that magnet's kinetic energy:
$$ P_L = I \times V_L = 10mA \times 0.5V = 5mW $$
Energy is conserved throughout, because the voltage across the resistive element of the coil actually reduces as the magnet accelerates, meaning that some of the energy that was being converted to heat is now being converted to motion instead.
It interesting to note that total power dissipation \$P_R + P_L\$ actually drops when the magnet is released and accelerates:
$$
\begin{aligned}
P &= P_R + P_L \\ \\
&= I V_R + I V_L \\ \\
&= I (V_R + V_L) \\ \\
&= I V_1 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Since V1 is constant at 1.5V, if current falls then necessarily so does total power dissipation.

If we somehow put 'brakes' on the magnet so that it doesn't get as high speed, then the emf would be less, right? Consider a magnet with a really heavy mass. The heavier the mass:

The slower the speed attained so the less emf, so the more power is consumed/dissipated in the coil
and the magnet still receives the same amount of kinetic energy. Because the integral of force x distance would be the same

is that right?

@ErikP Yes, induced $V_L$ is a function of velocity, not acceleration. That's why motors draw less current at speed, because $V_L$ (so-called "back-EMF") is greater, leaving lower voltage $V_R$ across $R$.

@ErikP It's ambiguous when you say "power dissipated in the coil", because some of that power $P_R$ is in its resistance, and some, $P_L$ in the magnetic field of its inductance. $P_R$ is energy lost, $P_L$ is energy that moves the magnet. In all cases $P_{TOTAL}=P_R+P_L$, AKA conservation of energy.

Yes, I see that I was a bit vague. I was referring to the fact that a heavier (as in more mass) magnet would cause less emf to manifest in the coil (so that V_L would be less than compared to a lighter magnet). Thus P_R should be greater, because smaller V_L means greater V_R. But the total work done on the magnet might be constant (i.e not depend on magnet mass), because force x distance does not seem depend on the mass. Although I am not sure about this last bit

Also interesting to note is that a stronger magnet (meaning more magnetic flux) means that the emf starts canceling out the battery's voltage sooner, meaning that - ceteris paribus - a stronger magnet won't be able to accelerate to as high a speed as a slightly weaker one.

Thank you for answering my question with such clear explanations
